# Erro ao tentar chamar o method salvar usando JSF Hibernate JPA Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa

Estou tentando salvar os dados do meu formulário porém quando clico em salvar da erro dizendo que "Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador".
Porém quando testo o method salvar usando `Junit` funciona norlmalmente .
Alguém pode está me ajudando ?

Essas são minhas declarações

Essa é a parte da entidade

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_login")
public class LoginEntity { // This the beginning of the class from the entity LoginEntity

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "cpf", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String cpf;

@Column(name = "login", nullable = false)
private String login;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

// This the end of the class from the entity LoginEntity
```

Essa é a parte do DAO

```
public class LoginDAO {

public void save(LoginEntity loginEntity) {

    try {
        EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        entityTransaction.begin();
        entityManager.persist(loginEntity);
        entityTransaction.commit();

        entityManager.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Essa é a parte do Bean

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "MB_LoginBean")
public class LoginBean {

// here is the beginning of the atributes from the class LoginBean
private LoginEntity loginEntity = new LoginEntity();

private LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();

// here is the end of the attributes from the class LoginBean

public void save() {

    dao.save(loginEntity);

}
```

Esse é o meu teste usando o Junit

```
@Test
public void salvar() {

    LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();
    LoginEntity loginEntity = new LoginEntity();

    loginEntity.setName("Teste salvar 5");
    loginEntity.setCpf("0175472");
    loginEntity.setPassword("145258");
    loginEntity.setLogin("admin5");

    dao.save(loginEntity);
}

}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver, eu estava usando o SessionFactory para a conexão do banco e  usando comandos do Entimanager, então criei minha conexão com o banco usando o persistence.xml e usei os comandos do EntityManger e funcionou tudo certo .

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, eu estava usando o SessionFactory para a conexão do banco e usando comandos do Entimanager, então criei minha conexão com o banco usando o persistence.xml e usei os comandos do EntityManger e funcionou tudo certo